# What causes kinetic force in a collision?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrons, collision

Okay, I'm not a physics person and know next to nothing about the subject, so I apologize if this is a stupid question.  I was wondering about something.  It's an accepted fact that two solid objects can not pass through each other.  I imagine this has something to do with repulsion between the electrons.  I don't know if it's the spin of the electrons or the electric charge that causes them to repel each other.  That's one thing I'm confused about.

Another thing, and this is possibly more of a chemistry question.  Say you have two metal cubes, and you press them together.  Metals are defined by the property of having loose valence electrons that cause them to conduct electricity more easily.  So when you think about it at a chemical level, you would expect the atoms of one cube to bond with the atoms of the other, causing them to stick together and form one solid object.  Of course this happens with magnets to some extent, but they're still not one body because you can easily pull them apart.  I can think of two possible explanations for this: one is that the crystal structures are not perfectly aligned, preventing the atoms from bonding; the other possible explanation is that there are air molecules between the two solids that cause electromagnetic repulsion.  On the whole, though, these are just conjectures and I really have no idea.

Comment: If you have the right surface finish and put two pieces of metal together they will stick, at least somewhat; to address that part.

Comment: Atomically clean metal surfaces will indeed stick together quite well. But, the universe has a lot of crud in it, and surfaces don't remain clean for long without exquisite care and feeding.

Comment: This might be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_welding